# Node + Express: How do the req and res variables have global scope without causing collisions?

Tags: node.js, express, global-variables

It seems that the `req` and `res` variables have global scope in Express (e.g. these variables are accessible regardless of the function scope). How is this achieved without causing collisions between simultaneous clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do not have global scope.

## Route

The route takes a handler function for each route.  That route is passed the `req` and `res` objects.

```
app.get('/my-route', myHandler);
```

## Handler

Your handler receives those objects and uses them.

```
exports.myHandler = function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello world");
);
```

## Closures

When you make a database call (or any other io bound call) you pass it a callback.  The `req` and `res` objects live in that callback as a closure.

```
exports.myHandler = function(req, res) {
  var weekday = req.query.weekday || "today";
  db.getWeather(weekday, function(err, result) {
    // `res` here is a closure
    if(err) { res.send(500,"Server Error"); return; }
    res.send(result);
  });
};
```

More about closures:  [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)